# What is "Roslyn Code Fixes" in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, roslyn

I see this in the newly released VS 2015:

[image: Roslyn Code Fixes]

However, clicking it does nothing (tried also double-clicking, shouting at it, etc.). How to interact with this element?

Comment: I mean, how loud did you shout?  In the future if you could post your shouts it would help us figure out what's wrong.  Right now we're just guessing.

Comment: @Jeff Laughing from 2018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they just released Resharper 9.1.2 today (July 21, 2015).

I had this same problem when I installed 9.1.1 Reshaper from Visual Studio 2015 in the Tools -> Extensions and Updates... menu.

It's likely best to just grab it on their site right now.

Comment: Not sure how does this explain "What is “Roslyn Code Fixes.” True it is a Reshaper thing, but what this has to do with Roslyn?!

Comment: @usefulBee The important detail is more so that it's bugged out for him and he doesn't understand why. At the end of the day it's just a context item that 'in theory' should give you options to refactor your code automatically for some useful purpose. Being that I've not seen that specific message since updating, I couldn't tell you what exactly it might be trying to correct or enhance. If you're ultra curious there might be Resharper documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's ReSharper 9.x causing this. They probably need to update for VS2015 RTM yet.